# How can I debug multiple charger plug/unplug cycles?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I need to stop and then start (restart) my MainService when the user plugs in the phone's charger.  To do this, I have a so-called GodService that registers a receiver for the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent, and then I restart MainService within that BroadcastReceiver.

I can post the code to that if necessary, but that seems to work fine, since, as soon as I start debugging I'm charging, and I can step through and see MainService get stopped and restarted.

My question is, how can I test this multiple times in a row (which I need to do), since I'll have to unplug the device, thus stopping my debugging session.  I'm sure there must be a way to debug the charging port removal, but I must not be searching with the correct terms.

Comment: You could use wireless adb connection, but I think that requires root

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for editing/clarifying the post, but why wouldn't the fact that I'm trying to debug in Android Studio be relevant?  In other words, might there be debugging features specific to that development environment that help with this?

Comment: Android Studio simply uses adb, but while you have a good  point, the question is not about the IDE itself

Comment: @cricket_007, if you'd like to submit an answer, I'll give you credit.  I used [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root) to setup wireless adb without root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually simulate the phone disconnect and reconnect via ADB. Here is the relevant code:

**Prior to Android 6+:**

Disconnect USB

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery set usb 0
```

Re-connect USB

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery set usb 1
```

**For Android 6+:**

Disconnect USB

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
```

Re-connect USB

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

---

**EDIT:**

Found a nice tuturial on how to mock different battery statuses. https://stanfy.com/blog/android-shell-part-1-mocking-battery-status/